# jQuery return value should be updated on resize

Tags: jquery, resize

I’ve got a jQuery function which returns a value. The value should be updated on resize—but unfortunately it isn’t …

http://jsfiddle.net/9undwx90/

jQuery

```
var rem;

function myFunction() {
  var rem = $( 'html' ).css( 'font-size' );
  return rem;
}

$( document ).ready( function () {
    console.log( myFunction() );
});

$( window ).resize( function () {
    console.log( myFunction() );
});
```

CSS

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules inside the `@media` blocks are invalid, since they're missing selectors. Use this:

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    html {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/koq1bh24/

Comment: Haha … *facepalm* Thanks a lot!